# Post method always returns nothing

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm trying to check if the given information is correct with PHP and MySQL ! (for android project) but when I send them and I try to use the POST method and compare them in my database the POST method always returns that there is no information have been sent.
so this is my code :

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "hochschule");

/* verify connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("connection failed : %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
/* recover data */
$benutzername = $mysqli->real_escape_string(isset($_POST['PARAM_LOGIN']));
$passwort = $mysqli->real_escape_string(isset($_POST['PARAM_PASSWORT']));

$result =  $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE benutzername    ='$benutzername' AND passwort='$passwort'");
$row = $result->fetch_row();
if($row[0] !=0) {
printf("true");
}else
printf("false");

/* Closing the connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

I use PHP 5.6 and MYSQL 5.7 and I used DHC plugin in google chrome to test the PHP script.
  **NOTE :**
**I think it's a problem of compatibility because i'm using PHP 5.6 and MYSQL 5.7 and this code i used it for earlier project and with earlier versions of PHP (5.5) and MYSQL (5.6) and it worked fine back then.**
Thank you for your help.

Comment: to return something use `echo` command like `echo $row[0];`

Comment: I did that ! it returned nothing ! it's like i didn't send anything

Comment: Did you just tried var_dump($_POST) to check if you sent anything?

Comment: same problem : without the 'isset' for the POST method it gives me 'Notice: Undefined index' wich means that it is empty !!

Comment: Does your `$_POST` contain anything? Try: `var_dump($_POST)`. Are you saving passwords in a hashed format (you should be!), then look for the hash and not the plain-text password. Are you sure you can access the count through `$row[0]`? Maybe try: `SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM user WHERE ben(...)` and then access it through `$row['count']`.

Comment: My problem is in the recover data process !! when i try to echo or print the result of $passwort or even the $benutzername it gives me nothing i tried to send the information with the android app and with the DHC plugin as i mentioned before but it returns nothing !! this is the plugin  ! would you please try it with me !! [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-rest-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that isset just returns a boolean value (true or false) - not the value of the parameter.

So you want something like this:

```
/* recover data */
$benutzername = null;
$passwort = null;

if(isset($_POST['PARAM_LOGIN'])) 
    $benutzername =$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['PARAM_LOGIN']);
if(isset($_POST['PARAM_PASSWORT'])
    $passwort = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['PARAM_PASSWORT']);
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply but your solution solved my problem and i didn't realise it because the plugin 'reslet' in google chrome was the issue ! thank you again